# InteropServices.ComException when closing a document after adding a new document from the ribbon

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I'm trying to write a Word add-in that uses a CustomTaskPane.  I'm able to create the CustomTaskPane and synchronize it between open documents, and I get no errors as long as I use the Word menu when I add a new or open an existing document.  However, if I add a new document through a ribbon button that calls `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Add()`, I start getting COMExceptions when I close documents.

The issue appears to be when I add a new document using the button click event in CtpMainRibbon.cs instead of through the Word menu, the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow` property is invalid after closing an open document.  On the get for the CurrentCustomTaskPane property, ActiveWindow returns a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'This command is not available because no document is open.'` at `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.get_ActiveWindow()`.  I've searched for the error but most of the issues are when people try to use the Word Interop on a server or an ASP.net page, but I'm getting this on my development machine.  Also, if I use the `Document.Add()` method, the Show button's check status doesn't display correctly (if I have a CustomTaskPane open in one document, then click the New Document button on the ribbon, the new document's Show button is checked even though the task pane isn't visible.  If I switch to a different window then switch back to the new document, the button's checked status updates to unchecked.

I've tried looping through `Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes` to see if there's a mismatch between the `ctp.Window.Hwnd` properties, but as far as I can tell, each `ctp.Window` has its own unique `Hwnd`.  I get the message even when there are other documents and windows open.

Here's the 2 pertinent code files.  I use CurrentCustomTaskPane so the ribbon button can sync up with the Visible property of the task pane.

ThisAddIn.cs:

```cs
private const string TaskPaneTitle = "Main Custom Task Panel";
public static CustomTaskPane CurrentCustomTaskPane
{
    get
    {
        return Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes
              .FirstOrDefault(ctp => !ctp.Control.IsDisposed && 
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow != null && 
                ReferenceEquals(ctp.Window, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow) && 
                ctp.Title == TaskPaneTitle);
    }
}

private void InternalStartup()
{
    Startup += ThisAddIn_Startup;
    Shutdown += ThisAddIn_Shutdown;
}

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.Documents.Count > 0)
    AddNewTaskPane(Application.ActiveDocument);
    Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event event4 = Application;
    event4.NewDocument += OnNewDocument;
    event4.DocumentOpen += OnDocumentOpen;
    event4.WindowActivate += ApplicationOnWindowActivate;
}

private static void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

private void OnNewDocument(Word.Document doc) => AddNewTaskPane(doc);

private void OnDocumentOpen(Word.Document doc) => AddNewTaskPane(doc);

private void ApplicationOnWindowActivate(Word.Document doc, Word.Window wn) => SetRibbonButtonToggle();

private void AddNewTaskPane(Word._Document doc)
{
    RemoveOrphanedTaskPanes();
    CustomTaskPane newPane = CustomTaskPanes.Add(new MainCustomTaskPanel(), TaskPaneTitle, doc.ActiveWindow);
    newPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft;
    newPane.DockPositionRestrict = Office.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
    newPane.Width = 700;
    newPane.VisibleChanged += TaskPaneOnVisibleChanged;
}

private void TaskPaneOnVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => SetRibbonButtonToggle();

private void SetRibbonButtonToggle()
{
    if (CurrentCustomTaskPane != null)
    Globals.Ribbons.CtpWordRibbon.RbnButtonShowTaskPane.Checked = CurrentCustomTaskPane.Visible;
}

private void RemoveOrphanedTaskPanes()
{
    foreach (CustomTaskPane ctp in CustomTaskPanes)
    {
        if (ctp.Window == null || ctp.Control.IsDisposed)
            CustomTaskPanes.Remove(ctp);
    }
}
```

CtpWordRibbon.cs:

```cs
private void RbnButtonShowCtp_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (ThisAddIn.CurrentCustomTaskPane != null)
        ThisAddIn.CurrentCustomTaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked;
}

private void RbnButtonCreateNewDocument_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Add();
}
```

There's obviously a difference between how Word handles adding a new document through the Word menu and adding it with the `Application.Documents.Add()` method.  How can I check to see if the `ActiveDocument` property is going to throw an COMException before I actually access it?  Or is there an better way to create a new document through the ribbon, or handle the `OnNewDocument` event so I'm not getting these errors?

Comment: Have you done any logging to find out whether the actions and their results in `AddNewTaskPane` are the same under both circumstances? All things being equal (the methods that create new documents aren't doing anything besides `Documents.Add`), I can't imagine Word is doing anything differently. `ActiveDocument`, however, is a slippery animal (just like `Selection`) and there could be something going on with that, depending on how it's being used. I think, in order to help, we'd need a [mcve] with clear steps how to set this up...

Comment: @CindyMeister One thing I did notice is that the `OnNewDocument` event handler is hit at different points.  If I go to Word -> New Document, the event is hit before a new window is created and the new document is displayed, but if I use the custom ribbon button that calls `Document.Add()`, it creates the document in a new window _then_ triggers the event handler.  This means there may be something different between the two `doc.ActiveWindow` objects.  I haven't seen anything different in the window properties, but I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right properties.